# Google+ Sharer - preview image

Tags: google-plus, facebook-sharer

I am using links like this : https://plus.google.com/share?url=www.myurl.com to share articles on Google+ from a website.

This works fine but the preview image of the share is not right.
I read in the Google doc that you need to specify an image like this:

```
<img itemprop="image" src="thumbnail.jpg" />
```

The thing is, the image I want to use is not being displayed on the page I want to share. I have specific thumbnail images (of smaller size than the images displayed in the article) that I'd like to use.

Is there a way to specify an image for Google, like the og:image tag for Facebook for example, without having to use the  tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to specify an image for Google, like the og:image tag for Facebook for example, without having to use the tag?

https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/:

> `2. Open Graph protocol`
>
> If the page contains Open Graph properties for the title, image, and description, they will be used for the +Snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, the schema.org tag that defines your page's preview image does not need to be displayed on the page, you could instead define it within your HEAD as metadata:

```
<meta itemprop="image" content="thumbnail.jpg" />
```